# availability of LAMBDA function

Tags: microsoft-excel-365

I'm waiting to get LAMBDA function in Excel.

Support page says it's available from 16.0.14729, I have 16.0.14931 which I believe is a higher version number, still I don't have it yet. Am I overlooking something?

MS support site (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67):

> LAMBDA function
> Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for
> Mac Excel for the web Availability
> Windows: **16.0.14729**
> Mac: 16.56 (Build 211211)
> Web: introduced 18-Mar-2022
> iOS: 2.56 (Build 211207)
> Android: 16.0.14729

My Excel version:
[image]

Comment: Although you should already have it, you might try to update to the latest version. Are you on the monthly update or semi-annual update?

Comment: I'm on semi annual update with enterprise license. I should be able to update to latest version, but need to convince couple of IT guys. I probably will wait until getting new versioin.

Comment: Is Lambda function available when you use Excel online?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes, it's available in Excel Online

Comment: Maybe you can follow the advice mentioned [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-is-the-lambda-function-not-available-in-excel/860e05c6-c50a-4ef9-9f4f-4a7e35065d1e),  "sign out from the Excel app> Quit all Office apps> Restart your PC> Open the Excel> Sign in and check the result.".

Comment: Very good question, I couldn't have posted the exact same! I have the same build, a semi-annual prenumeration. I have Let but not Lambda!